# uploading a document to one location and have it replicated on other sites document library

Tags: 2007, development, document-library

What would be the best way of  uploading a docuemnt to one location and have it replicated on other sites document library.

I know I can use workflow, event receivers but then there will be duplications of document, isn't there anyway we can link a single document to multi site's document libraries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you would have to do is make a single document store with multiple views. and it's the views that differ for different people.

Just design a tagging system for the documents and views to compensate, and use a single document store.

[update]

In SharePoint you can create views in multiple ways for a list or a library. The document store web part is no exception.

Add a Managed Metadata column to the document store, then add a filter to the view dependent on this column. Your event receiver would then automatically tag the document depending on the location of the web part you are using to view the document store.

Using this method once setup, you can have any number of document stores with a single bucket, and you can control if it is possible to view other virtual document stores with this tag filtering.

This is the SharePoint way, one location for files and one place to collaborate.

Comment: thanks but I think I will need a bit more of explanation please.